# My WITH SQL statement doesn't work as it's supposed to, it is not recognising the input as a table, why?

Tags: sql

When I run:

```
SELECT fid 
FROM field 
WHERE name = 'DisplayName' AND sid = 8;
```

against my database, I get a 1 row by 1 column table, with column name `fid` and value `998`.

Here is my `WITH` statement:

```
WITH display_name_fid AS 
(
    SELECT fid 
    FROM field 
    WHERE name = 'DisplayName' AND sid = 8
)
SELECT * 
FROM sval 
WHERE display_name_fid.fid = 998;
```

This is returning an error:

> SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "display_name_fid"¶  Position: 116

Also worth noting when I do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sval 
WHERE fid = 998
```

I get a big table, and this is what I expect the query above to output, but it returns the error instead. Any ideas where it is going wrong?

Comment: `display_name_fid`  is never used in SELECT of WITH.

Comment: You are not referencing the CTE in your main SELECT statement, just a column from it. This won’t work

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
WITH display_name_fid AS (
    SELECT fid from field where name='DisplayName' AND sid=8
)
select * 
from sval s
join display_name_fid d on s.fid = d.fid;
```